# Why primary key take duplicate value

Tags: sql

Here i creat a simple table

```
create table xyz(ID int,Name varchar(50),Email Varchar(50))
```

And then i did some alter on xyz table

```
ALTER TABLE xyz
ALTER column ID int Not Null
ALTER TABLE xyz
ALTER column Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
```

I Added Primary key on xyz table

```
ALTER TABLE xyz
ADD CONSTRAINT  PK-ON_DIFColumn
PRIMARY KEY (ID,Name)
```

Here both allow dublicate column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `id` to be the primary key and `name` to be unique:

```
ALTER TABLE xyz ADD CONSTRAINT  PK_ON_DIFColumn PRIMARY KEY (ID);
ALTER TABLE xyz ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_xyz_name UNIQUE (Name);
```

A composite key (such as a primary key) applies to the combination of values in the two columns, not each column separately.